# What is the maximum entropy distribution with a mean of 0, stdev of 1, skew of 1 (instead of zero), and kurtosis of 1 (instead of 3)?

Tags: normal-distribution, moments, kurtosis, lagrange-multipliers

As we know, there are an infinite number of distributions with mean of zero and variance of one.

One of the special things about the normal distribution is that is has the maximum entropy.

(https://www.deeplearningbook.org pp. 645).

Is there an equivalent maximum entropy distribution with mean zero, variance one, kurtosis of one (versus zero for normal distribution) and skew one (versus three for normal distribution)?

More generally, is there a derivation for an *arbitrary number of higher order statistical moments*, perhaps using KKT/Lagrangians?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141743/what-is-the-maximum-entropy-distribution-given-mean-variance-skewness-and-kur

Comment: The normal has zero skew.